# The following assertion was thrown running a test: pumpAndSettle timed out Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown running a test:
pumpAndSettle timed out

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      WidgetTester.pumpAndSettle. (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:667:11)


(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This post helped me when I faced this issue

https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-pumpandsettle-timed-out-175044

so basically remove the **tester.pumpAndSettle()**

and replace it with

`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 1)); }`

Comment: OMG this line saved me. Good Job!